# Primary function proceeds while a vital component is still being generated. How do I make the function wait?

Tags: node.js, express, request

I'm working on a Node project that primarily uses Express and Request to present stats from a particular API endpoint.

I stumbled upon a problem when I a POST request gets made at a certain route.

Desired result: Server makes a request to an Overwatch API endpoint, and returns the response from the API to the route /lookup.

Actual result: Server makes a request to an Overwatch API endpoint, Node proceeds to finish the called function without completing the request, leaving the response 'undefined'.

Here's the app.js file I have, and the console result to go with it.

```
//Load npm modules
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');

//Set obj 'app' to express();
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/lookup', (req, res, next) => {
    const battletag = req.body.battletag;
    console.log("running");
    var stats = lookupStats(battletag);
    console.log("lookupStats() completed. Attempting to render stats.");
    res.render(stats);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('The application is running on localhost:3000!')
});


function apiRequestObj(battletag) {
    var requestObj = {
        uri: "https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/" + battletag + "/blob?platform=pc",
        timeout: 10000,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31'
        }
    }
    return requestObj;
}

function apiRequest(requestObj) {
    request(requestObj, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            return "Error: " + err;
        } else {
            var result = JSON.parse(body);
            result = result.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats;
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
    });
}

function lookupStats(battletag) {
    battletag = battletag.replace('#', '-');
    console.log("Searching Battletag: " + battletag);
    var requestObj = apiRequestObj(battletag);
    var apiResult = apiRequest(requestObj);
    console.log(apiResult);
    return apiResult;
}
```

---

```
The application is running on localhost:3000!
running
Searching Battletag: Unreal-11505
undefined
lookupStats() completed. Attempting to render stats.
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at extname (path.js:1431:5)
    at new View (/Users/neil/Dropbox/Programming/Web Development/owapi/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:56:14)
    at EventEmitter.render (/Users/neil/Dropbox/Programming/Web Development/owapi/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/neil/Dropbox/Programming/Web Development/owapi/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at app.post (/Users/neil/Dropbox/Programming/Web Development/owapi/app.js:22:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/neil/Dropbox/Programming/Web Development/owapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/neil/Dropbox/Programming/Web Development/owapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/neil/Dropbox/Programming/Web Development/owapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/neil/Dropbox/Programming/Web Development/owapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
{ level: 61,
  comprank: 2031,
  games: 116,
  win_rate: 53.21,
  losses: 51,
  rank_image: 'https://d1u1mce87gyfbn.cloudfront.net/game/playerlevelrewards/0x0250000000000928_Border.png',
  wins: 58,
  ties: 7,
  prestige: 1,
  avatar: 'https://d1u1mce87gyfbn.cloudfront.net/game/unlocks/0x02500000000002F7.png',
  tier: 'gold' }
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can make Node wait for the response from the API endpoint before proceeding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a callback function to the asynchronous function and then make the function call the callback. Anything to be done after the request is completed, should be done in the callback.

```
function apiRequest(requestObj, callback) {
  request(requestObj, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
    } else {
        var result = JSON.parse(body);
        result = result.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats;
        console.log(result);
        return callback(null, result);
    }
  });
}

function lookupStats(battletag) {
  battletag = battletag.replace('#', '-');
  console.log("Searching Battletag: " + battletag);
  var requestObj = apiRequestObj(battletag);
  apiRequest(requestObj, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return console.error("error: ", err);
    return console.log("result: ", result);
  });
}
```

Similarly, lookupStats if being called from somewhere, should also accept a callback and then calls the callback when the request is completed.